# 2 censoring ticks, 2 different colors

Tags: tikz-pgf

I'm trying to create a plot with two distributions, two different censoring points and two different colors. I've managed to create both distributions and give them different colors. I've also created both censoring points, but I'm failing at changing one of the censoring point's color to red. I've tried several combinations but I always seem to get both censoring points plotted under the same color. Any suggestions? I attach a pic and code. Many thanks!

```
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Insert title}


\begin{figure}[!ht]
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    declare function={gamma(\z)=
    2.506628274631*sqrt(1/\z)+ 0.20888568*(1/\z)^(1.5)+ 0.00870357*(1/\z)^(2.5)- (174.2106599*(1/\z)^(3.5))/25920- (715.6423511*(1/\z)^(4.5))/1244160)*exp((-ln(1/\z)-1)*\z;},
    declare function={gammapdf(\x,\k,\theta) = 1/(\theta^\k)*1/(gamma(\k))*\x^(\k-1)*exp(-\x/\theta);}
%    declare function={gammapdf(\x,\k,\theta) = 1/(\theta^\k)*1/(gamma(\k))*\x^(\k-1)*exp(-\x/\theta);}
]

\begin{axis}[
  no markers, domain=0:7.0, samples=100,
  axis lines=left, xlabel=$y_t^i$, ylabel=$f_y(.)$,
  every axis y label/.style={at=(current axis.above origin),anchor=east},
  every axis x label/.style={at=(current axis.right of origin),anchor=north},
  major x grid style={draw=cyan!50!cyan},
  height=6cm, width=11cm,
  %xtick={6.5}, 
  xtick style={color=cyan},
  xtick={6.0,6.5}, 
  ytick=\empty, 
  %xticklabels={},
  xticklabels={$\bar y$, $\bar y'$},
  %xticklabels={$\bar n(\theta_t)$},
  %xticklabels={$\bar n$, $\bar n$},
  %xticklabels={$\bar n(\theta^2_t$), $\bar n(\theta^1_t)$},
  enlargelimits=false, clip=false, axis on top,
  grid = major,
  xmax=10
  ]

\addplot [very thick,red!50!red,domain=0:6.5] {gammapdf(x,9,0.5)};
\addplot [very thick,cyan!50!cyan,domain=0:6] {gammapdf(x+0.5,9,0.5)};
%\addplot [fill=cyan!20, draw=none, domain=0:6.5] {gammapdf(x,9,0.5)} \closedcycle;


\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\caption{Insert Caption}
\end{figure}

\end{frame}
```

[image]

Comment: By the way, `colour!50!colour` is redundant. Use only `colour`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You were using (possibly (ab)using) the grid to draw the censoring points, and each grid (`major` and `minor`) has one style; it cannot be changed for only a part of the `grid`.

The initial possibility is to use `xtick` for one censoring point and `extra x ticks` for the other. One can use `major` grid style and the other an independently-set `minor` grid style.

But this is klunky and breaks down if there's more than 2 censoring points to draw or if you want to do more sophisticated styling. So, in this case, I think it's easiest to draw the censoring points manually, with

```
\draw[cyan] (6.0,0) -- ++(rel axis cs:0,1);
\draw[red] (6.5,0) -- ++(rel axis cs:0,1);
```

The `rel axis cs:0,1` draws automatically up to the top of the axis "box", regardless of the scaling and/or limits.

You could even do this with a command; perhaps something like

```
\newcommand{\censorpt}[2][]{\draw[#1] (#2,0) -- ++(rel axis cs:0,1);}
```

To be used as `\censorpt[dashed,green]{5.5}`.

I also removed the redundant color mixing (`red!50!red` is equivalent to `red`) and added `typeset ticklabels with strut` for better alignment of the tick labels.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.11}
\newcommand{\censorpt}[2][]{\draw[#1] (#2,0) -- ++(rel axis cs:0,1);}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    declare function={gamma(\z)=
    2.506628274631*sqrt(1/\z)+ 0.20888568*(1/\z)^(1.5)+ 0.00870357*(1/\z)^(2.5)- (174.2106599*(1/\z)^(3.5))/25920- (715.6423511*(1/\z)^(4.5))/1244160)*exp((-ln(1/\z)-1)*\z;},
    declare function={gammapdf(\x,\k,\theta) = 1/(\theta^\k)*1/(gamma(\k))*\x^(\k-1)*exp(-\x/\theta);}
]

\begin{axis}[
  no markers, domain=0:7.0, samples=100,
  axis lines=left, xlabel=$y_t^i$, ylabel=$f_y(.)$,
  every axis y label/.style={at=(current axis.above origin),anchor=east},
  every axis x label/.style={at=(current axis.right of origin),anchor=north},
  major x grid style={draw=cyan},
  height=6cm, width=11cm,
  %xtick={6.5}, 
  xtick={6.0,6.5}, 
  ytick=\empty, 
  %xticklabels={},
  xticklabels={$\bar y$, $\bar y'$},
  %xticklabels={$\bar n(\theta_t)$},
  %xticklabels={$\bar n$, $\bar n$},
  %xticklabels={$\bar n(\theta^2_t$), $\bar n(\theta^1_t)$},
  enlargelimits=false, clip=false, axis on top,
  xmax=10,
  typeset ticklabels with strut,
  ]

\addplot [very thick,red,domain=0:6.5] {gammapdf(x,9,0.5)};
\addplot [very thick,cyan,domain=0:6] {gammapdf(x+0.5,9,0.5)};
\draw[cyan] (6.0,0) -- ++(rel axis cs:0,1);
\draw[red] (6.5,0) -- ++(rel axis cs:0,1);
\censorpt[green,dashed]{5.5}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

The key `typeset ticklabels with strut` and the default `axis cs` coordinate system are part of `pgfplots` v1.11. If stuck with an older version for whatever reason, you might use

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\newcommand{\censorpt}[2][]{\draw[#1] (axis cs:#2,0) -- ++(rel axis cs:0,1);}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    declare function={gamma(\z)=
    2.506628274631*sqrt(1/\z)+ 0.20888568*(1/\z)^(1.5)+ 0.00870357*(1/\z)^(2.5)- (174.2106599*(1/\z)^(3.5))/25920- (715.6423511*(1/\z)^(4.5))/1244160)*exp((-ln(1/\z)-1)*\z;},
    declare function={gammapdf(\x,\k,\theta) = 1/(\theta^\k)*1/(gamma(\k))*\x^(\k-1)*exp(-\x/\theta);}
]

\begin{axis}[
  no markers, domain=0:7.0, samples=100,
  axis lines=left, xlabel=$y_t^i$, ylabel=$f_y(.)$,
  every axis y label/.style={at=(current axis.above origin),anchor=east},
  every axis x label/.style={at=(current axis.right of origin),anchor=north},
  major x grid style={draw=cyan},
  height=6cm, width=11cm,
  %xtick={6.5}, 
  xtick={6.0,6.5}, 
  ytick=\empty, 
  %xticklabels={},
  xticklabels={$\bar y$, $\bar y'$},
  %xticklabels={$\bar n(\theta_t)$},
  %xticklabels={$\bar n$, $\bar n$},
  %xticklabels={$\bar n(\theta^2_t$), $\bar n(\theta^1_t)$},
  enlargelimits=false, clip=false, axis on top,
  xmax=10,
  ]

\addplot [very thick,red,domain=0:6.5] {gammapdf(x,9,0.5)};
\addplot [very thick,cyan,domain=0:6] {gammapdf(x+0.5,9,0.5)};
\draw[cyan] (axis cs:6.0,0) -- ++(rel axis cs:0,1);
\draw[red] (axis cs:6.5,0) -- ++(rel axis cs:0,1);
\censorpt[green,dashed]{5.5}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

where `typeset ticklabels with strut` is removed and `axis cs:` is prefixed to the coordinates.

Comment: Thanks! This looks great. However, when I tried imbedding your code I get the following error message:

"Package pgfkeys Error: I do not know the key '/tikz/typeset ticklabels with strut' and I am going to ignore it. Perhaps you misspelled it. [\end{frame}]"

If I comment out the strut line I get the right image, but the censoring lines are off to the left. I'm not sure if it relevant, but I'm writing this code into a beamer presentation. Any thoughts? Thanks again for your help.

Comment: Also the "\pgfplotsset{compat=1.11}" command is delivering the following error message: 
Package pgfkeys Error: Choice '1.11' unknown in key '/pgfplots/compat/anchors'. I am going to ignore this key. [\pgfplotsset{compat=1.11}]
Thanks again for any help.

Comment: `typeset ticklabels with strut` and defaulting to `axis cs` are both new in v1.11 of `pgfplots`. You need to update the `pgfplots` package.

Comment: Many thanks! Any way that perhaps one can do this without the update? I have a bad internet connection to download the new packages and I'm under a tight deadline. Again, thank you so much for your help.

Comment: Remove the `typeset ticklabels with strut` and add `axis cs:` to the first coordinate of each `\draw` command, like so: `\draw[cyan] (axis cs:6.0,0) -- ++(rel axis cs:0,1);`. This is why we ask for compilable examples...

Comment: Thanks a lot! That worked beautifully. Thanks again for helping me out. I really appreciate it.

Comment: @Colenso, you're welcome; glad I could help! Since it seems my post answered your question, please consider marking it as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below its vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)).